# deleting a string in a file in c

Tags: c, file, argv

In my homework we have a text file with people in it for example:

```
-
Audra Kirkland
768479054
Ante 5
Avellino
-
Leilani Carson
10493141
Felis 3229
Sahiwal
-
```

in the terminal the argv[0] is the name of the program argv[1] is 'DELETE' argv[2] is the ID of the person argv[3] is the name of the file.
(mirsham.exe delete 1234567 mirsham.txt)
in the main function the code is:

```
if(strcmp(argv[1], "DELETE") == 0 && strcmp(argv[3], "mirsham.txt") == 0)
    {

        char ID[15];
        strcpy(ID, argv[2]);
        deletePerson(fp, ID);
    }
```

the deletePerson function is

```
void deletePerson(FILE *fp, char ID[])

{

    char buffer[6000];

    fp = fopen("mirsham.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file!");
        return;
    }

    while (fgets(buffer, 6000, fp) != NULL)
    {

        if ((strstr(buffer, ID)) != NULL)
        {

            fprintf(stdout, "Match found!");
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "No match found");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The code works it prints the match found if i input an ID that exists in the file
but what's not working for me is that I have to delete a whole block which means the name the address and the ID each block is between two '-', tried seperating the blocks by counting them but it did not work.
help would be much appreciated and if you could help me with some code that would be wonderful.

Comment: Typically you just read in all entries, write out a new file (without the entries you don't want), and if everything went as planned, you move the old file out of place, rename the new file, and if once again everything works you can remove the old file.

Comment: there are 512 lines in the file,
how can i copy the file to another file without a specific person ?

Comment: Open the file for read, open an output file for write, define four char[] variables to hold a full entry, in loop read each entry at a time with fgets, if the entry do not match the delete id write the four variables to the output file etc...

Answer (score 0):

One quick way to achieve this:

```
bool deletePerson(const char filename[], char id[])
{
    FILE *istream = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!istream) return false;
    
    FILE *ostream = fopen("tmp.txt", "w+");
    if (!ostream) return false;
    
    char block[1024];
    while (fscanf(istream, "-\n%1023[^-]", block) == 1) {
        if (strstr(block, id))
            continue;
        
        fprintf(ostream, "-\n%s-\n", block);
    }
    
    fclose(istream);
    fclose(ostream);
    
    rename("tmp.txt", filename);
    return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
int main(void)
{
    deletePerson("people.txt", "768479054");
}
```

File `"people.txt"`:

```
-
Leilani Carson
10493141
Felis 3229
Sahiwal
-
```

**Note:** You must check your [`rename()`'s compiler implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41926099/does-the-c-rename-function-delete-files).